# When does a View know its own size in Android? (width & height)

Tags: android, view

I get confused with all the methods that get called, and since there is no View-lifecycle description anywhere, I'd like to know when does an Android View knows its exact size, so it can tell it to an observer?
Maybe the methods onLayout or onMeasure are useful, but I'm looking for the best way for achieving this.
thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A View doesn't know its own size until it is drawn on the screen.  To get the values once they are drawn you can use an `OnGlobalLayoutListener` like so:

```
<yourView>.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
    new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            //getWidth() and getHeight() now have values
            //you can remove this layout listener too if you don't need it anymore
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your guess is correct - `onMeasure()` it's a first time when View informed about it's dimensions. By the way, `onMeasure()` may be called several times depending on layout complexity.

Quoted from Jason Ostrender's "Android UI Fundamentals Develop and Design"

> The onMeasure method is called by the system to determine the size of
>   the view and its children. It’s passed two integers that are actually
>   MeasureSpecs. A MeasureSpec is just a combination of a mode flag and
>   an integer size value. It’s implemented as an integer to reduce
>   unneeded object allocations. The mode tells the view how it should
>   calculate its size. These are the possible modes:
>
> UNSPECIFIED. The parent view has placed no constraints on this view;
>   it can be any size it wants.
>   AT_MOST. The view can be any size less
>   than or equal to the MeasureSpec size.
>   EXACTLY. The view will be
>   exactly the MeasureSpec size regardless of what it requests.
>
> When you create a custom view and override the onMeasure method, it is
>   your job to properly handle each of these cases. In addition, the
>   measuring contract dictates that you call the setMeasuredDimensions
>   method with the determined integer size values. If you fail to do
>   this, an IllegalStateException will be thrown.

So, parent view tells to child view about some constraints he must comply and child calculates its own size assuming this information.

If you want an example of how to use `onMeasure()` proper way you can look at this https://gist.github.com/syndarin/8799233. I have played around custom views some time ago and this is one of my experiments - simple shape view, square or circle.